# SQL to retrieve row where 'Field Y' had a previous value of 'Unfulfilled' and now ='Fulfilled'?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

I created a Query that called records updated within the last day using the code below. However, the "UpatedAt" field may change after the order has been fulfilled so I cannot use this field alone to determine which customers enter the Data extension that is fired after the query.

I cannot find an SQL function that queries only records that have a previous value of "Unfulfilled" for "Field Y" and now have a value of "Fulfilled" for that field.

Any advice is appreciated. I am a newb to SFMC and queries. Thank you!

```
SELECT 
OrderId
, SubscriberKey
, EmailAddress
, CancelledAt
, Fulfillment
, UpdatedAt 
FROM [OrderDE] 
WHERE FieldY = 'fulfilled' 
AND CONVERT(datetime, UpdatedAt)
```

....

Answer (score 0):

From the basic understanding of your schema, it wouldn't be possible to query the previous value of a field once it's been updated.

You could create two different fields in your data extension - one for fulfilled and one for unfilled e.g. Boolean flags. You will also want Fulfilled / Created dates for each. Then you could query the values of each.

Alternatievly, you'd have to create 3 data extensions (identical schemas)
1) Fulfilled 
2) Unfulfilled
3) The delta

You will want to snap-shot your data e.g. into the fulfilled & unfulfilled data extension and a date-time.

In the 3rd data extension, your query would then compare the data between your Fulfilled and Unfilled data extensions and produce your desired result.